# handler file(.ashx) file does not load in windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7, handler

I use **iis 6.1 with windows7**.If i create handler file(.ashx) in my asp.net website,It was not load when i Execute that in Browser.Did any **System changes are need to load the Handler File in windows7** properly?.But the same handler load properly on Windows 2008.and ***my .Net specfication are visual studio 2008 version 9.0.21022.8 RTM*** and my .net frame work is 3.5 SP1

Comment: `System changes are need to load the Handler File in windows7 properly?`

Yes, they released IIS 7 (Windows 2008) and subsequently 7.5 (Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2). IIS6 isn't natively supported on Windows 7 - you can install backwards compatibility for management, but the underlying system has changed dramatically.

Could you supply some additional details: What version(s) of .net are you running? Does the handler have 32-bit dependencies? Are you running in integrated or classic mode?

Comment: and bring forth the code

Comment: Why on earth do you use IIS 6.1 on Win 7? And yes, please show the code for handler. Are you sure it's a problem with your handler on IIS 6.1? Can you see IIS loading other handlers? ASPX for example?

Comment: When you host your application on latest IIS, then all handlers gets loaded automatically. But in older versions , that doesn't happen, you have to manually load your handler in IIS handlers before hosting your application

Comment: How are you executing it in the browser and what is the error message?

Answer (score 4):

IIS 6.1 is not supported on windows 7. In addition see the following link and enable iis as a windows feature and retry your service. If you need to test for an iis 6 deployment consider debugging on a platform that supports iis 6 like windows server 2003.

Why doesn't your install work, missing registry keys, iis metabase changes this is just the tip of the iceberg.

[Can I install IIS 6 & IIS 7.5 on the same Windows 7 machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701954/can-i-install-iis-6-iis-7-5-on-the-same-windows-7-machine)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not sure why you need to use IIS 6.1 however it looks to me that you have IIS misconfiguration issues.
Here is what you need to check:

- Make sure you have appropriate application pool associated with the website (Classic or Managed) depending on your application structure.
- Check if ASP.NET is registered appropriately with ISS if not you can browse to appropriate .NET version. The utility is aspnet_regiis.exe, it is located under %WindowsDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.y.zzzz\ and you should call it with the -i parameter: aspnet_regiis.exe -i
- Check under MIME Types if there are .ashx type is defined.